# Transpose Database with different data types in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner with MySQL or any other database-language. I been tasked with creating an import out of a MySQL-database. Unfortunately the import only expects on column for the values while the database has one column for each different query.

With some entries on stackoverflow and the MySQL documentation I was able to transpose the database. Unfortunately there are different data types. I also learned about SQL Fiddle and spent some time to recreate the database there. But i suppose the testing for the sql expression was easier there.

I used the function select/union all (After learning that MySQL is not the same as SQL and therefore unpivot doesn't work). And was happy that I was able to keep the 2 columns "id" and "reporting date" as most examples I found on stackoverflow only kept 1 column.

**The Problem is that some columns have the datatype "int" while other have "decimal (2)". The union command only works on the same datatype or formats it that way so that the decimal points are cut off! How do I adjust the MySQL expression to have one column with int and decimal? I suppose it is some way of join?**

The real database has currently 43 columns that need to be switched, with 9 of those decimal.

From the logic of the next software used it might be okay for all data to be decimal (2) as I can change the type in that software.

Also is it a problem if it is used on a german database with comma instead of point for the decimal divider?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59cb76/8

Code used so far:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(`id` int, `created_at` datetime, `reporting_date` date, `improvement` int, `internal` int, `external` int, `value` decimal(2));

INSERT INTO Table1
(`id`, `created_at`, `reporting_date`, `improvement`, `internal`, `external`, `value`)
VALUES
(1, '2018-08-08 10:33:00', '31.07.2018', 1, 4, 3, '2.76'),
(2, '2018-08-08 10:34:00', '31.01.2018', 1, 4, 2, '3.12'),
(3, '2018-08-08 10:35:00', '31.12.2017', 1, 4, 5, '4.23');
```

Transpose query:

```
select id, reporting_Date, 'improvement' Field, improvement Value
from table1
union all
select id, reporting_Date, 'internal' Field, internal Value
from table1
union all
select id, reporting_Date, 'external' Field, external Value
from table1
union all
select id, reporting_Date, 'value' Field, value Value
from table1
```

Base Data

```
| id | reporting_Date | improvement | internal | external | value |
|----|----------------|-------------|----------|----------|-------|
|  1 |     2031-07-20 |           1 |        4 |        3 |   2.76|
|  2 |     2031-01-20 |           1 |        4 |        2 |  3.12 |
|  3 |     2031-12-20 |           1 |        4 |        5 |  4.23 |
```

expected output:

```
| id | reporting_Date |       Field | Value |
|----|----------------|-------------|-------|
|  1 |     2031-07-20 | improvement |     1 |
|  2 |     2031-01-20 | improvement |     1 |
|  3 |     2031-12-20 | improvement |     1 |
|  1 |     2031-07-20 |    internal |     4 |
|  2 |     2031-01-20 |    internal |     4 |
|  3 |     2031-12-20 |    internal |     4 |
|  1 |     2031-07-20 |    external |     3 |
|  2 |     2031-01-20 |    external |     2 |
|  3 |     2031-12-20 |    external |     5 |
|  1 |     2031-07-20 |       value |  2.76 |
|  2 |     2031-01-20 |       value | 3.12  |
|  3 |     2031-12-20 |       value |  4,23 |
```

current output

```
| id | reporting_Date |       Field | Value |
|----|----------------|-------------|-------|
|  1 |     2031-07-20 | improvement |     1 |
|  2 |     2031-01-20 | improvement |     1 |
|  3 |     2031-12-20 | improvement |     1 |
|  1 |     2031-07-20 |    internal |     4 |
|  2 |     2031-01-20 |    internal |     4 |
|  3 |     2031-12-20 |    internal |     4 |
|  1 |     2031-07-20 |    external |     3 |
|  2 |     2031-01-20 |    external |     2 |
|  3 |     2031-12-20 |    external |     5 |
|  1 |     2031-07-20 |       value |     3 |
|  2 |     2031-01-20 |       value |     3 |
|  3 |     2031-12-20 |       value |     4 |
```

Sorry for the formating and beginner question and thanks for any help.

Ranger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in your `SELECT` query. Infact, there is no basis for this statement (of yours), in official MySQL documentation; it is wrong (plain and simple):

> The union command only works on the same datatype or formats it that
>   way so that the decimal points are cut off!

Now, a closer look at the SQL Fiddle quickly revealed that your `DECIMAL` datatype definition in the Schema is utterly wrong. Now, note the following from [MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html):

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The
>   ranges of values for the arguments are as follows:
>
> M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65.
>
> D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.
>
> If D is omitted, the default is 0. If M is omitted, the default is 10.

Now, check your table definition closely:

> CREATE TABLE Table1
>      (id int, created_at datetime, reporting_date date, 
>       improvement int, internal int, external int, 
>       value **decimal(2)**);

You have not defined the `value` column as a decimal with 2 precision points, but a decimal type with only maximum two digits before decimal point, and **zero precision**.

So, even if you are Inserting the values with some precision, they all are getting truncated at the time of storage. A simple `SELECT * FROM Table1` would reveal that all the values in the `Value` column has lost their precision. Check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59cb76/14

---

Now, all you need to do is simply fix the datatype definition of `value` to `DECIMAL(10,2)`:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (`id` int, `created_at` datetime, `reporting_date` date, `improvement` int, `internal` int, `external` int, `value` decimal(10,2))
;

INSERT INTO table1
    (`id`, `created_at`, `reporting_date`, `improvement`, `internal`, `external`, `value`)
VALUES
    (1, '2018-08-08 10:33:00', '31.07.2018', 1, 4, 3, '2.76'),
    (2, '2018-08-08 10:34:00', '31.01.2018', 1, 4, 2, '3.12'),
    (3, '2018-08-08 10:35:00', '31.12.2017', 1, 4, 5, '4.23')
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select id, reporting_Date, 'improvement' Field, improvement Value
from table1
union all
select id, reporting_Date, 'internal' Field, internal Value
from table1
union all
select id, reporting_Date, 'external' Field, external Value
from table1
union all
select id, reporting_Date, 'value' Field, value Value
from table1;

| id  | reporting_Date | Field       | Value |
| --- | -------------- | ----------- | ----- |
| 1   | 2031-07-20     | improvement | 1     |
| 2   | 2031-01-20     | improvement | 1     |
| 3   | 2031-12-20     | improvement | 1     |
| 1   | 2031-07-20     | internal    | 4     |
| 2   | 2031-01-20     | internal    | 4     |
| 3   | 2031-12-20     | internal    | 4     |
| 1   | 2031-07-20     | external    | 3     |
| 2   | 2031-01-20     | external    | 2     |
| 3   | 2031-12-20     | external    | 5     |
| 1   | 2031-07-20     | value       | 2.76  |
| 2   | 2031-01-20     | value       | 3.12  |
| 3   | 2031-12-20     | value       | 4.23  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r3RcRjdzYHNDzgZmyt6kUa/0)

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer.
I've must misinterpreted the data type section of the MySQL-documentaion. As well as the data type syntax especially the ommision part.

Comment: I thought using SQL-Fiddle will be helpfull for me and for the description of the problem. But maybe while finding the right code for the transpose goal I created another problem that wasn't there in the first place.

I'll now try the code with the real data. But will keep an eye out for the data type syntax as i saw in the german language code also the decimal (2) description which I only translated.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is happening due to repeated aliases. You don't need to repeat alias in each UNION query -

```
select id, reporting_Date, 'improvement' Field, improvement Value
from table1
union all
select id, reporting_Date, 'internal', internal
from table1
union all
select id, reporting_Date, 'external', external
from table1
union all
select id, reporting_Date, 'value', value
from table1
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. This cleans up the code but unfortunately doesn't solve the decimal problem.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59cb76/9

Comment: Repeated alias does not make any difference whatsoever. MySQL simply uses the aliases/column name used in the very first select query inside the UNION

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, I completely agree on that. I think here the real issue is, the type casting of improvement column. Since it is declared as INT it is converting all values to int when using in UNION.